# Spring Boot App with WebSockets and without WebContainer

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I am supposed to make an application with Spring Boot and WebSockets. But I should not use Jetty, JavaEE or Tomcat (or any other webcontainer servlet stuff). Is that even possible using "plain spring boot"???? Every example I am finding uses some kind of WebContainer. How would Spring Boot work without that to manage Http Connections and WebSocket communication?

Comment: So SpringBoot seems to be a ServletDispatcher. But doesn't that always require a ServletContainer, e.G. Tomcat? Or does Spring have it's own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt find any working example with websockets and without a servlet. So it seems mandatory.